# Getting the ID of Object after it's submitted using :remote => true in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a Invoicing app in rails and submitting a form using :remote => true, I'm then using Jquery to append the contents of the form to bottom of the invoice.

However I'm looking to add a delete button, and I don't have a way of knowing the ID of the element I just submitted without refreshing the page. Is there a way to fix this or am I going about this the wrong way?

my form is as follows if this helps:

```
<%= form_for [@inv, Line.new], :remote => true do |f| %>

<div class="form-container">
  <%= f.label :service %>
  <%= f.text_field :service, autofocus: true, class: "service", input_html: {autocomplete: 'off'} %>
</div>

<div class="form-container">
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_field :description, class: "description", input_html: {autocomplete: 'off'} %>
</div>

<div class="form-container">
  <%= f.label :price %>
  <%= f.text_field :price, class: "price", input_html: {autocomplete: 'off'} %>
</div>


<%= f.submit "Add", class: "line-button" %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks!

edit:

Line Controller (The thing I'm submitting)

```
class LinesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update, :show, :delete]
  before_action :logged_in_user


  def create
    @inv = Inv.find(params[:inv_id])
    @line = @inv.lines.new(line_params)

    if @line.save
      flash[:success] = "Successfully created Comment!"
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Your comment must contain a body!'
    end

  end

  def destroy
    @line = Line.find(params[:id])
    @line.destroy
  end


  private

  def line_params
    params.require(:line).permit(:service, :description, :price)
  end

  def correct_user
    @user = Line.find(params[:id]).user
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
  end


end
```

Javascript file:

```
var ready = function() {

  $(".line-button").click(function(){
    var serviceContent = $(".service").val();
    var descriptionContent = $(".description").val();
    var priceContent = $(".price").val();

    $(".line-container").append("<div class='line'><p class='service-paragraph'>" + serviceContent + ":</p> <p class='description-paragraph'> " + descriptionContent + "</p> <p class='price-paragraph'>||£" + priceContent + "</p>||</div>" );

    setTimeout(function(){ //timeout because without it the form cleared to fast and a empty form was submitted
      $(".service").val("");
      $(".description").val("");
      $(".price").val("");
      $(".service").focus();
    }, 100);

  });

};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code and javascript for dealing with it once the form is submitted

Comment: Oops, sorry! Updated the main post with it.

Comment: So basically move most of that javascript to a `create.js.erb` file in the lines view folder.  You'll have access to `@line` and therefore can do `@line.id`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to fix this?

As you are submitting the form using `:remote => true` you must have `create.js` or something file for that action

so just render a partial with delete button you will get id in that action pass it to the partial